# Which language can be used to program PIC10F200/202/204/206?

Tags: c, assembly, microcontroller, iot, pic

In a pursuit to use a low cost, less pin micro-controller, I have ended up with the PIC series PIC10F200/202/204/206 as a prospective choice. My use cases for them involve using just one or two pins to control external peripherals like DC motors, LEDs. And using at most one OR two sensors for input. I have some experience with Arduino but no experience with PIC series at all.

Looking at the projects over the internet, it seems that the higher series of PIC micro-controllers like PIC16*, PIC18* can be programmed in both C and assembly language. But for the series - PIC10F200/202/204/206, I see programs being developed only in assembly language. I have read somewhere that it is due to less memory available in the PIC10F* micro-controllers. I can program in C, but have no idea about assembly language. It seems difficult to learn as well, and hence could be a dead end for me for now if assembly is the only language I can use.

So, I want to ask, is it NOT possible to program these specific microcontrollers using C language? Is it really a constraint that I need to use assembly language only?

OR

Is it just my misunderstanding and the PIC10F* series can be programmed with C language just like PIC16* and PIC18* series.

Please let me know if you need any further information from my side before answering this.

Thanks,

Anurag

Comment: As the [page](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/compilers) is stating: *MPLAB XC8 supports all 8-bit PIC® and AVR® microcontrollers (MCUs)*

Comment: I suggest that you try the C compiler if it exists. Maybe you've seen asm examples because people who coded them master asm and don't want to bother with a compiler and the options.

Comment: A long time ago, there was a "tiny C" compiler avaliable for the very basic PICs. But bear in mind, they had no user stack and only an 8-level call stack so it wasn't much of an implementation.

Comment: In general you wouldnt really "want" to program a PIC with C as your resources are so extremely limited.  Just look at the specs on the parts you mentioned.  384 bytes of flash 16 bytes of ram.  That is tough for assembly much less C you would struggle to bootstrap in that.   The pic instruction set is not C compiler friendly, not that microchip didnt do a good job with their backend.

Comment: Unless there is some very very specific reason, use something other than an old PIC, on par with price, same or lower power, significantly more flash/ram/clock with newer alternatives.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Thanks for taking time to look at my query. Yes, I think MPLAB supports programming in both assembly and C. But I am more interested in knowing that given the small size of memory on these microcontrollers, am I constrained only to use assembly to program? As some other responses and posts on internet have indicated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Thanks for taking time to look at my query. Yes, I think MPLAB compiler supports programming in both assembly and C. Do you think that the given the small size of memory on these microcontrollers, am I constrained only to use assembly to program? As some other responses and posts on internet have indicated.

Comment: worst case: 1) create C code 2) code doesn't fit 3) learn assembly (lol :)) 4) disassemble the code 5) trim the unnecessary parts & optimize yourself... 6) work from assembly from now on. Good luck.

Comment: @old_timer - Thanks for taking time to look at my query. If such is the case, I think I should step up to either a higher PIC series or with a new MCU in the same PIC series. What would be a good flash ram size which will be able to bootstrap, load and run a moderate size C program. I will make my search based on that. What are your thoughts on newer PIC MCUs in the same series like PIC10F322 and PIC10F320? They also should not be able to fit in C, right? Here is the datasheet - http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001585D.pdf

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - That too sounds like a good approach ... Definitely worth a try if I am going the route of such small memory on an MCU ... Thanks !

Comment: @Fredrik - Ok, thats good to know. Responding further in your answer.

Comment: the assembly programing on these pics is super simple... there is basically one accumulator register and everything goes to or comes from that... pretty tedious... if you have played any of the zactronic games like tis-100, schenzhen io, it is basically like that

Comment: @GradyPlayer - Thanks for the insight on assembly programming required for these pics here. Incase C does not work, I can give a shot to assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which language can be used to program PIC10F200/202/204/206?

Technically, you can use the MPLAB XC8 compiler; it can target these parts.

Practically, you will likely need to use assembly.  The parts you're looking at all have either 16 or 24 **bytes** of RAM, 256 or 512 instructions worth of program memory, and a 2-level call stack. Programming in C under these conditions is extremely difficult.

I would advise that you use a different part. The PIC10F200 series is quite old (~2004); there are much more capable parts available at [comparable](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC10F322) prices from Microchip, or [much lower](https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2019/08/12/the-terrible-3-cent-mcu/) from other vendors.

Comment: I agree, programing old chips can be a pain too, if you have to provide voltage above the usb programmers voltage... pic32's come in dips, and in small quantities cost about the same... they are overkill for most things, but if you have built in quad decoders, usb, adc's etc you can do a lot more hobbying without having to re-read a new datasheet...

Comment: @GradyPlayer Also an excellent point! The low pin count of the PIC10F200 series makes in-circuit programming particularly awkward.

Comment: @duskwuff - Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

What would be a good ram size which will be able to bootstrap, load and run a moderate sized C program. I will make my search based on that. Like you have already suggested, what are your thoughts on newer PIC MCUs in the same series like PIC10F322 and PIC10F320? Will they be able to fit in C code? Here is the datasheet - ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001585D.pdf

Comment: At 64B RAM, running C code on the PIC10F320 series will still be an extremely tight fit. It's not quite as tiny as the '200 series, but it isn't big either. Whether this is workable will really depend on your application.

Comment: @duskwuff - But at 64B RAM, atleast it should be able to run a small C application right? My example small app will be taking input from an IR Sensor and running one DC motor and an LED based on the signal received.

Comment: @duskwuff - Also, in your experience, what would be a good ram size on any MCU which will be able to bootstrap, load and run a moderate sized C program? I am not good with C and hence do not know the exactly what all is run along with a C program in an MCU and how much memory the runtime takes. Hence asking. I can understand C code a bit as have programmed in other languages, hence asking this level of detail.

Comment: @Anurag How long is a piece of string? It's going to depend entirely on your application. A "moderate sized C program" which implements an image editor will require much more memory than one which implements a calculator, for instance.

Comment: @duskwuff - Like I mentioned in my last comment, my small app will be taking input from an IR Sensor and running one DC motor and an LED based on the signal received. That's the size I am talking about. But may be I missed mentioning some other variables here which need to be considered before we can determine if 64B RAM on PIC10F320/PIC10F322 is enough for running such an application. But I got an idea of what you are saying and Thank You very much for your help here :) ...

Comment: @Anurag Please also look at [ATtiny](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATtiny85) and [STM8](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm8-8-bit-mcus.html#products). These are from Microchip (previously atmel) and ST.