Requesting a simple code for PIC10F200 using MPLAB XC8 Compiler
I can't program this microchip (using a PicKit5, should be no issues), either because its too old or I'm lacking a lot of knowledge.
So the program gets written correctly with no errors, but when I'm hooking up the microchip, making sure it gets a steady 5V from my source(Arduino Uno, I use the VDD(+) and VSS(-) for getting the microchip powered, if it's wrong please make a note), but the thing is, it does not light up anything, I have 4LEDs for each output just in case its a 1ms flash on any but there is none.
I just want to make one of the outputs to send a signal for 20s(for example) and than wait 20s and repeat the cycle (in my situation I chose GP1).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protect (Code protection off)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // Master Clear Enable (GP3/MCLR pin fuction is digital I/O, MCLR internally tied to VDD)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main()
{
    while (1)
        TRISGPIO = 0b00000000;
        // GPIO = 0b00000000; 
        __delay_ms(100);
        GPIObits.GP1 = 1;
        __delay_ms(100);
        GPIObits.GP1 = 0;
}

This is the last attempt of my code. Not the brightest.


In your code the delay time is 100ms not 20s!

"So the program gets written correctly with no errors," - how have you determined that it is programmed?  Have you written it to the correct state address? Do you have the correct run-time  start-up code?  What tool did you use to write the flash?  Do you have debug hardware?  If so use the debugger to determine whether the code is present and running at all.  If you are relying on LED activity to indicate success, you also have to have an understanding of electronics in order to have connected the LED correctly.  That is not a given, you need to provide evidence of all these things.

@Clifford the small window at the bottom of the program states clearly, how it cleaned the previous code and was successfully written. There were no pointing errors/unreadable lines. As for the connections, I will provide a sketch.

"There were no pointing errors/unreadable lines" I have no idea what that means, especially in the context of flashing the code.  Successful build and successful flash programming are separate and independent.   Would it not be simpler and less ambiguous to just post the text content of the window you refer to _in the question?  It is all diagnostic information - even if you think it adds nothing.

Also on C on PIC10F200: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963143/which-language-can-be-used-to-program-pic10f200-202-204-206

Going code-blind!  You said you could not program the chip, but clearly you can but the code you were programming it with was not correct.  C is not Python.

Sorry I interpreted "programming the chip" to mean writing to the flash.  You were successfully programming the chip with incorrect code.

@Clifford as long as people provide me the fixes I do not mind the "mud that gets me dirty", I also thought you knew how MPLAB displays the errors on the left side of the line you are writing the code on. Do mind I lack a lot of knowledge in all POVs, be it electronics, physics or coding. Looking forward for you all, big brainiacs', to provide for the better of all.

put { and } to define your while (1) loop.
void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        TRISGPIO = 0b00000000;
        // GPIO = 0b00000000; 
        __delay_ms(100);
        GPIObits.GP1 = 1;
        __delay_ms(100);
        GPIObits.GP1 = 0;
    }
}

Without them your code only do:
    while (1)
        TRISGPIO = 0b00000000;

